# Crazy touch screen

Tags: touchscreen, xiaomi

I've experienced strange behavior of my phone for almost a week now. Sometimes my phone detects a lot of touch gestures at a time while there should be only one which is mine. This happens and I have no idea why my phone does behave like this. This is really annoying. If someone has faced with such a problem and found solution please help me.

Imagine you pull the trigger of a gun in a video game with intention to shoot one bullet but somehow you shoot a whole clip by pulling once. Every bullet is a touch and when you "pull the trigger" you actually touch your display.

P.s. my phone is Xiaomi Redmi 4X.

Comment: Have you ever dropped it? I think it sounds like a bad digitizer, but it could be something else.

Comment: Thanks. I have but I think those were not really bad. How can check whether it is what you've said and how can I fix  if it is?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a digitizer problem, which I'm pretty sure means you'll have to replace the whole screen. [Here](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/235912/How+to+decide+whether+to+replace+LCD+screen+digitizer+or+just+LCD) is a link that might help you on deciding what to do. I would use that site for any parts that you might need. Hope it works for you!